# What is the LINQ equivalent for the following SQL query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0

[image: These are the 3 tables used here]

T-SQL query:

```
select 
   PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME.NAME, SUM(SALES_PRICE) as PRODUCT_SALES 
from SALES_PRODUCT_DETAILS
join PRODUCT_NAME on PRODUCT_NAME.ID = SALES_PRODUCT_DETAILS.PRODUCT_ID
where 
    SALES_ID in 
        (select SALES_ID 
         from SALES 
         where SALES_DATE >= '2011-11-13' and SALES_DATE <= '2011-11-16')
group by 
    PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME.NAME
```

What is the equivalent LINQ query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this I think would do the trick.

```
from s in SALES_PRODUCT_DETAILS
join p in PRODUCT_NAME on s.PRODUCT_ID equals p.ID
where SALES.Any(sales => 
             sales.SALES_DATE >= new DateTime(2011, 11, 13) && 
             sales.SALES_DATE <= new DateTime(2011, 11, 16) &&
             sales.SALES_ID == s.SALES_ID)
group s by new { s.PRODUCT_ID, p.NAME } into g
select new
{
   g.Key.Name,
   g.Key.PRODUCT_ID,
   PRODUCT_SALES = g.Sum(x => x.SALES_PRICE)
}
```

Comment: `g.Name` and `g.PRODUCT_ID` don't work, instead I've written `g.Key.NAME` and `g.Key.PRODUCT_ID` and that works fine. And you've written `select` two times. Could you please edit your answer so I can mark it as right answer?